# Work distribution - roundrobin in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, round-robin

**Problem statement as Figures**
[image: Configuration of Data]

**Expected results assuming threshold count = 9**
[image]

**Problem Statement as Text** - 
There are T Clients which serves a Server X & below is the configuration.

T0,T1,T2,T3 :--- X0
T4,T5,T6,T7 :--- X1
T8,T9,T10,T11 :--- X2
T12,T13,T14,T15 :--- X3

T0 to T3 Serves in round-robin to X0 Until a threshold of tokens are served
Lets Say Eg: Threshold is 9, serving sequence will look like
T0,T1,T2,T3,T0,T1,T2,T3,**T0**

T4 to T7 Serves in round-robin to X1 Until a threshold of tokens are served
Lets Say Eg: Threshold is 9, serving sequence will look like
T4,T5,T6,T7,T4,T5,T6,T7,**T4**

T8 to T11 Serves in round-robin to X2 Until a threshold of tokens are served
Lets Say Eg: Threshold is 9, serving sequence will look like
T8,T9,T10,T11,T8,T9,T10,T11,**T8**

T12 to T15 Serves in round-robin to X3 Until a threshold of tokens are served
Lets Say Eg: Threshold is 9, serving sequence will look like
T12,T13,T14,T15,T12,T13,T14,T15,**T12**

***SO SEQUENCE WILL LOOK LIKE THIS***

T0,T1,T2,T3,T0,T1,T2,T3,**T0**   :--- X0
T4,T5,T6,T7,T4,T5,T6,T7,**T4**   :--- X1
T8,T9,T10,T11,T8,T9,T10,T11,**T8**    :--- X2
T12,T13,T14,T15,T12,T13,T14,T15,**T12**  :--- X3

***AFTER ITERATING ALL T's NEXT SEQUENCE WILL LOOK LIKE THIS***

T1,T2,T3,T0,T1,T2,T3,T0,**T1**  :--- X0
T5,T6,T7,T4,T5,T6,T7,T4,**T5**  :--- X1
T9,T10,T11,T8,T9,T10,T11,T8,**T9**    :--- X2
T13,T14,T15,T12,T13,T14,T15,T12,**T13**   X3

as you can see , the last used T' is skipped in next iteration.

I managed to write the code snippet code is here, but in my code I am not able to fairly distribute the tokens as expected in table(where last used T' after reaching threshold should be skipped in next iteration).

Please suggest.

```
#include <iostream>

int CurrentT = 0;
int No_Of_T_Per_X = 4;
int OutputX = 0;
int No_Of_X = 4;
int Valid_T[16] ={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
int Processed_Tokens[4] = {0,0,0,0};
int THRESHOLD[4] = {9,9,9,9};
int LastT_Used[4] = {0,0,0,0};

static unsigned int getTargetX(unsigned int id, unsigned int       num_T_per_X) 
{ return id / num_T_per_X; } 

bool batch = false;
int main()
{
    int prev_SPMindex = -1;
    int next_SPMindex = 0;

    for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++) { // Looping to test some random no. of tokens..
     if ( Processed_Tokens[OutputX] >= THRESHOLD[OutputX]){    
     THRESHOLD[OutputX] = THRESHOLD[OutputX] + 9;
     //LastT_Used[OutputX] = CurrentT;
     prev_SPMindex = next_SPMindex;
     CurrentT = prev_SPMindex;
 }

 CurrentT = (CurrentT + 1) % (sizeof(Valid_T)/sizeof(int));  // Currently Processed T'

 if(((CurrentT % No_Of_T_Per_X) == 0)){
      next_SPMindex = CurrentT -1;
      CurrentT = prev_SPMindex;
      CurrentT = (CurrentT + 1) % (sizeof(Valid_T)/sizeof(int)); 
 }

 OutputX =    getTargetX(Valid_T[CurrentT], No_Of_T_Per_X); // Currently Processed X'           
 Processed_Tokens[OutputX] += 1; // Increasing the Count of Tokens to test

}

return 0;

}
```